# Getting the size of jpeg image

Tags: c

I am trying to get the size of an image file by doing the following

```
fp = fopen(path,"rb");
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
```

The problem is that when I get to the first fseek my program terminates. I have tested with a text files and it works and have seen some other examples online where the same method applies to images.

Comment: `* Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability).` from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: What is the value of FP at the second line? Have you bothered to check if the return value of fopen is NULL?

Comment: @nhahtdh Is tehre any other way to get the size of an image file?

Comment: how did you given the filename? post the format

Comment: Another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659307/how-to-get-large-file-size-using-c

Comment: Wrong link. This is the correct one: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html

Comment: @user1072706 how did you give filename?

Answer (score 1):

you are very closed, just a small difference

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename", "rb");
long size = 0;

if (f == NULL)
 printf("error"); //handle error
else
{
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(f);
}
```

Comment: What is pfile? For simplicity we are assuming fp is not NULL.

Comment: It doesn't make sense - why would you open the file twice in different mode? And error checking should be done on `f`, not `pFile`, since it is what we are going to operate on.